# AccessViolationException in Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer constructor

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, sapi

My app is getting an `AccessViolationException` when calling the default constructor of the `Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer` class. This only happens on one particular machine (so far at least), which is a Surface Pro 3 running Windows 8.1. All other machines with the app installed do not experience this issue.

My code is something like this:

```
class Speech
{
    private Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer _Synthesizer;
    public Speech()
    {
        SetVoice();
    }

    private void SetVoice()
    {
        try
        {
            // Exception is raised here
            _Synthesizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace that shows up in the Event Logs looks like this:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
    at Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer..ctor()
    at ... Speech.SetVoice()
    at ... Speech..ctor()
```

I captured a dump file using ProcDump and can see this in the stacktrace (it doesn't show "my code" just the code after it):

```
sapi.dll!CSpObjectTokenEnumBuilder::CheckTokenSignature(struct ISpDataKey *) Unknown
sapi.dll!CSpObjectTokenEnumBuilder::AddTokensFromDataKey(struct ISpDataKey *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *) Unknown
sapi.dll!CSpObjectTokenCategory::InternalEnumTokens(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,struct IEnumSpObjectTokens * *,int) Unknown
sapi.dll!CSpObjectTokenCategory::EnumTokens(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,struct IEnumSpObjectTokens * *) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!SpEnumTokens(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,struct IEnumSpObjectTokens * *) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::InstalledVoicesStatic::get_AllVoices(struct Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<class Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::VoiceInformation *> * *) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::InstalledVoicesStatic::get_DefaultVoiceWithRank(struct Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::IVoiceInformation * *,unsigned int *) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::CSpeechSynthesizer::GetDefaultVoice(struct Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::IVoiceInformation * *,unsigned int *) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::CSpeechSynthesizer::CreateSynthesizerObject(void) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::CSpeechSynthesizer::RuntimeClassInitialize(void) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Details::MakeAndInitialize<class Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::CSpeechSynthesizer,class Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::CSpeechSynthesizer>(class Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::CSpeechSynthesizer * *) Unknown
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.dll!Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::InstalledVoicesStatic::ActivateInstance(struct IInspectable * *) Unknown
```

Its really weird that the error seems to be escaping the try/catch block. This is only on one customer's machine

Any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your customer has bad data in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Speech\Voices\Tokens`, which is where SAPI stores the information about what voices are installed on the system.

Clearly, some keys are present (given that the code is trying to add a token from the registry key), but the values are corrupt, causing the AV in the native code.

Other areas to check (if applicable to your system) would be:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Speech\Voices\Tokens`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WOW6432Node\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Speech\Voices\Tokens`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\WOW6432Node\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Speech\Voices\Tokens`

Comment: Good thought. I'll check that.

Comment: I took exports of the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Speech` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Speech` parts of the registry. `HKLM` is identical on the problem machine and my local machine. `HKCU` is different, but I can't say if anything is corrupt. There are no `Voices\Tokens` in `HKCU`. Thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify my comment, there are three voice tokens in `HKLM` (none in `HKCU`) and they are the same three as present on other systems (David, Hazel, Zira) with all of the same exact values (verified by a WinDiff of the .reg export from the two different systems).

Comment: I've tracked it down to a particular app being installed; that app does do stuff with the voices. It put them in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens`. It appears that removing that fixes it. How can I tell what exactly is corrupt in that so that I could pass it on to the developer of that other application?

Comment: Alternatively, how can I get around this in my app since a try/catch block doesn't catch the exception (and obviously I can't access the registry from my app)?

Comment: I talked with some other devs here, and apparently it's (intentionally) very difficult to catch access violations in native code within WinRT apps.

Comment: @Tim - Can you contact me with the details of the particular application that's causing the problem?

Comment: Sure. How should I contact you? Contact form on your blog?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that would be best.